# Angular model not updating - Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive where the model is not updating like I think it is supposed to.  Here is my html:

```
      <div class="text-area-container">
        <textarea ng-model="chatText" ng-keyup="updateCount(chatText)"></textarea>
      </div>
     <input ng-disabled="disableCommentButton()" value="Comment" ng-click="addMessage(chatText)"/>
```

As you can see I have a `ng-model` attached to the `<textarea>`.  I don't know if this affects anything, but I also have a `ng-keyup` attached to the element, that takes the model and looks at how many characters are in it.  The last piece is I have a `ng-disable` on an input that is evaluated by a function.  Here is my the `link` function of my directive:

```
  link: function(scope) {
    scope.chatText = '';

    scope.countRemaining = 500;

    scope.updateCount = function(chatText) {
      scope.chatText = chatText;
      scope.countRemaining = scope.maxChatCount - chatText.length;
    };

    scope.disableCommentButton = function() {
      return _.isUndefined(scope.encounter) || _.isEmpty(scope.chatText);
    };
  }
```

The problem is that my `scope.chatText` is always undefined in the `disableCommentButton` method.  I thought that by attaching a model to an element in the `html`, the I would have access to it on the scope.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try...

```
scope.disableCommentButton = function() {
  return _.isUndefined(this.encounter) || _.isEmpty(this.chatText);
}
```

Comment: Why did that work?  `scope.encounter` was working, but `scope.chatText` was not working.  I don't know if `scope.chatText` not being defined earlier in the file had anything to do with it.

Comment: with scope being a global variable at the time of your function declaration it was referring to the out-dated scope. referring to this within the function refers to the new scope object.

Comment: So the scope changes? When does the scope become out of date?

Comment: scope is simply a container object. In your code you are changing scope when you add the encounter and chatText properties. So, really scope can change at anytime based on how your code changes it.